# ffmpeg ndk multiple definition libavcodec.a(golomb.o)

Tags: c++, eclipse, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I'm trying to link ffmpeg as static libraries with android NDK but I'm getting 'multiple definition' error' errors as below. I've also included my build script which runs through everything just fine but when I come to using the libraries in Eclipse with the ADT plugin, I can't get anywhere.

From this it looks like it wants something to do with VLC. I don't want anything to do with VLC, just ffmpeg for video streaming. Everything works fine with shared libraries, but I'm after a very tiny player because I'm restricted to space on the device.

EDIT: Also 'log2_tab_tab.o' has multiple definitions.

```
error: jni/libs\libavcodec.a(golomb.o): multiple definition of 'ff_golomb_vlc_len'  Ffplayer            C/C++ Problem
error: jni/libs\libavcodec.a(golomb.o): multiple definition of 'ff_interleaved_dirac_golomb_vlc_code'   Ffplayer            C/C++ Problem
error: jni/libs\libavcodec.a(golomb.o): multiple definition of 'ff_interleaved_golomb_vlc_len'  Ffplayer            C/C++ Problem
error: jni/libs\libavcodec.a(golomb.o): multiple definition of 'ff_interleaved_se_golomb_vlc_code'  Ffplayer            C/C++ Problem
error: jni/libs\libavcodec.a(golomb.o): multiple definition of 'ff_interleaved_ue_golomb_vlc_code'  Ffplayer            C/C++ Problem
error: jni/libs\libavcodec.a(golomb.o): multiple definition of 'ff_se_golomb_vlc_code'  Ffplayer            C/C++ Problem
error: jni/libs\libavcodec.a(golomb.o): multiple definition of 'ff_ue_golomb_len'   Ffplayer            C/C++ Problem
error: jni/libs\libavcodec.a(golomb.o): multiple definition of 'ff_ue_golomb_vlc_code'  Ffplayer            C/C++ Problem
error: jni/libs\libavcodec.a(log2_tab.o): multiple definition of 'ff_log2_tab'  Ffplayer            C/C++ Problem
error: jni/libs\libavformat.a(log2_tab.o): multiple definition of 'ff_log2_tab' Ffplayer            C/C++ Problem
jni/libs\libavformat.a(golomb_tab.o): previous definition here  Ffplayer            C/C++ Problem
jni/libs\libavutil.a(log2_tab.o): previous definition here  Ffplayer            C/C++ Problem
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a-hard/libffplayer.so] Error 1   Ffplayer            C/C++ Problem
```

Using the latest branch of ffmpeg (2.4.3) my build script for Android (using toolchain 8 because it's old hardware I'm working with) and wanting the NEON hardware support:

```
export ANDROID_NDK=/home/carl/dev/ndk
export TOOLCHAIN=/home/carl/temp/ffmpeg
export SYSROOT=$TOOLCHAIN/sysroot/
$ANDROID_NDK/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh \
    --platform=android-8 --install-dir=$TOOLCHAIN

export PATH=$TOOLCHAIN/bin:$PATH
export CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
export LD=arm-linux-androideabi-ld
export AR=arm-linux-androideabi-ar

CFLAGS="-O3 -Wall -mthumb -pipe -fpic -fasm \
  -finline-limit=300 -ffast-math \
  -fstrict-aliasing -Werror=strict-aliasing \
  -fmodulo-sched -fmodulo-sched-allow-regmoves \
  -Werror=implicit-function-declaration \
  -Wno-psabi -Wa,--noexecstack"
#  -D__ARM_ARCH_5__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5E__ \
#  -D__ARM_ARCH_5T__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__ \
#  -DANDROID -DNDEBUG"

EXTRA_CFLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon \
              -mfloat-abi=softfp -mvectorize-with-neon-quad \
              -DHAVE_ISNAN -DHAVE_ISINF
              -std=c99"
EXTRA_LDFLAGS="-Wl,--fix-cortex-a8"

FFMPEG_FLAGS="--prefix=/home/dev/ffmpeg/build \
  --target-os=linux \
  --arch=arm \
  --enable-cross-compile \
  --cross-prefix=arm-linux-androideabi- \
  --enable-shared \
  --enable-static \
  --enable-small \
  --disable-symver \
  --disable-doc \
  --disable-ffplay \
  --disable-ffmpeg \
  --disable-ffprobe \
  --disable-ffserver \
  --disable-avdevice \
  --disable-avfilter \
  --disable-encoders  \
  --disable-muxers \
  --disable-demuxers \
  --disable-filters \
  --disable-devices \
  --disable-decoders \
  --enable-decoder=mjpeg \
  --enable-decoder=mp1 \
  --enable-decoder=mp2 \
  --enable-decoder=mp3 \
  --enable-decoder=mpeg1_vdpau \
  --enable-decoder=mpeg1video \
  --enable-decoder=mpeg2video \
  --enable-decoder=mpeg4 \
  --enable-decoder=mpeg4_vdpau \
  --enable-decoder=mpegvideo \
  --enable-decoder=mpeg_xvmc \
  --enable-decoder=h261 \
  --enable-decoder=h263 \
  --enable-decoder=h263i \
  --enable-decoder=h263p \
  --enable-hwaccel=h263_vaapi \
  --enable-hwaccel=h263_vdpau \
  --enable-hwaccel=mpeg1_vdpau \
  --enable-hwaccel=mpeg1_xvmc \
  --enable-hwaccel=mpeg2_dxva2 \
  --enable-hwaccel=mpeg2_vaapi \
  --enable-hwaccel=mpeg2_vdpau \
  --enable-hwaccel=mpeg2_xvmc \
  --enable-hwaccel=mpeg4_vaapi \
  --enable-hwaccel=mpeg4_vdpau \
  --enable-demuxer=aac \
  --enable-demuxer=ac3 \
  --enable-demuxer=h261 \
  --enable-demuxer=h263 \
  --enable-demuxer=pcm_s16be \
  --enable-demuxer=pcm_s16le \
  --enable-demuxer=pcm_s8 \
  --enable-demuxer=mpegps \
  --enable-demuxer=mpegts \
  --enable-demuxer=mpegtsraw \
  --enable-demuxer=mpegvideo \
  --enable-demuxer=rtp \
  --enable-demuxer=rtsp \
  --enable-parser=aac \
  --enable-parser=mpegvideo \
  --enable-parser=ac3 \
  --enable-parser=h261 \
  --enable-parser=h263 \
  --enable-parser=mjpeg \
  --enable-parser=mpeg4video \
  --enable-parser=mpegaudio \
  --enable-protocol=rtp \
  --enable-protocol=file \
  --enable-protocol=ftp \
  --enable-protocol=tcp \
  --enable-protocol=http \
  --enable-protocol=udp \
  --enable-protocol=pipe \
  --enable-protocol=unix \
  --enable-network \
  --disable-swscale  \
  --enable-asm \
  --enable-memalign-hack \
  --disable-golomb \
  --enable-stripping \
  --enable-pthreads \
  --disable-symver \
  --enable-version3"

./configure $FFMPEG_FLAGS --extra-cflags="$CFLAGS $EXTRA_CFLAGS" \
  --extra-ldflags="$EXTRA_LDFLAGS"

make clean
echo "Project now cleaned"
make -j4

echo "Stripping multiple references from libraries"
arm-linux-androideabi-ar d libavcodec.a log2_tab.o
arm-linux-androideabi-ar d libavutil.a log2_tab.o

echo "Done..."
```

And this is the Android.mk file which works fine.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := avutil
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs\libavutil.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := avformat
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs\libavformat.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := avcodec
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs\libavcodec.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := ffplayer
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ffplayer.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := C:\DEV\ffmpeg\

LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -llog -ljnigraphics -lGLESv2 -ldl
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -lstdc++ -lc
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -lz -lm

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libavutil libavformat libavcodec

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

If anybody can spot what's wrong with this it would be so appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by using a similar build method someone else used and just added my own options. This one also copies the folders "bin", "lib", "include" and the "share". All I needed then was to add the "lib" and "include" folders to my project. Phew!

```
#!/bin/bash

NDK=/home/carl/dev/ndk
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-9/arch-arm
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86/
PREFIX=/home/carl/temp/ffmpeg/

function build_one
{
./configure --target-os=linux --prefix=$PREFIX \
--enable-cross-compile \
--enable-runtime-cpudetect \
--enable-asm \
--arch=arm \
--cc=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc \
--cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
--disable-stripping \
--nm=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm \
--sysroot=$PLATFORM \
--enable-nonfree \
--enable-small \
--disable-symver \
--disable-doc \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffmpeg \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-ffserver \
--disable-avdevice \
--disable-avfilter \
--disable-encoders  \
--disable-muxers \
--disable-demuxers \
--disable-filters \
--disable-devices \
--disable-decoders \
--enable-decoder=mjpeg \
--enable-decoder=mp1 \
--enable-decoder=mp2 \
--enable-decoder=mp3 \
--enable-decoder=mpeg1_vdpau \
--enable-decoder=mpeg1video \
--enable-decoder=mpeg2video \
--enable-decoder=mpeg4 \
--enable-decoder=mpeg4_vdpau \
--enable-decoder=mpegvideo \
--enable-decoder=mpeg_xvmc \
--enable-decoder=h261 \
--enable-decoder=h263 \
--enable-decoder=h263i \
--enable-decoder=h263p \
--enable-hwaccel=h263_vaapi \
--enable-hwaccel=h263_vdpau \
--enable-hwaccel=mpeg1_vdpau \
--enable-hwaccel=mpeg1_xvmc \
--enable-hwaccel=mpeg2_dxva2 \
--enable-hwaccel=mpeg2_vaapi \
--enable-hwaccel=mpeg2_vdpau \
--enable-hwaccel=mpeg2_xvmc \
--enable-hwaccel=mpeg4_vaapi \
--enable-hwaccel=mpeg4_vdpau \
--enable-demuxer=aac \
--enable-demuxer=ac3 \
--enable-demuxer=h261 \
--enable-demuxer=h263 \
--enable-demuxer=pcm_s16be \
--enable-demuxer=pcm_s16le \
--enable-demuxer=pcm_s8 \
--enable-demuxer=mpegps \
--enable-demuxer=mpegts \
--enable-demuxer=mpegtsraw \
--enable-demuxer=mpegvideo \
--enable-demuxer=rtp \
--enable-demuxer=rtsp \
--enable-parser=aac \
--enable-parser=mpegvideo \
--enable-parser=ac3 \
--enable-parser=h261 \
--enable-parser=h263 \
--enable-parser=mjpeg \
--enable-parser=mpeg4video \
--enable-parser=mpegaudio \
--enable-protocol=rtp \
--enable-protocol=file \
--enable-protocol=ftp \
--enable-protocol=tcp \
--enable-protocol=http \
--enable-protocol=udp \
--enable-protocol=pipe \
--enable-protocol=unix \
--enable-network \
--disable-swscale  \
--enable-asm \
--enable-memalign-hack \
--enable-stripping \
--enable-pthreads \
--disable-symver \
--enable-version3 \
--extra-cflags="-I/home/android-ffmpeg/include -fPIC -DANDROID \
-D__thumb__ -mthumb -Wfatal-errors -Wno-deprecated \
-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -marm -march=armv7-a" \
--extra-ldflags="-L/home/android-ffmpeg/lib"
make -j4 install

$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar d libavcodec/libavcodec.a inverse.o
$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld -rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PREFIX/lib  -soname libffmpeg.so -shared -nostdlib  -z,noexecstack -Bsymbolic --whole-archive --no-undefined -o $PREFIX/libffmpeg.so libavcodec/libavcodec.a libavfilter/libavfilter.a libavresample/libavresample.a libavformat/libavformat.a libavutil/libavutil.a libswscale/libswscale.a -lc -lm -lz -ldl -llog -lx264 --warn-once --dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker $PREBUILT/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/libgcc.a
}

build_one
```